# String building and form component access from class

Tags: c#

**Background**

I am writing a program, which collects different events (key press, mouse position, and others) and sends a single string to a serial port.
There is a small part of the program, where a key is pressed, to control movement (forward - W key; left - A key, Forward-left - WA key).
When an event happens, a method is invoked, which grabs a numeric string and processes in the FinalStringClass Class. On the main form , there is a method, which assigns collected value to a label.
However, I am encountering a problem with code due to lack of experience in programming :(

**Main Form:**

```
    Serial port;
    FinalStringClass fstr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //... Serial port settings
        timer.Start();
        fstr = new FinalStringClass(UpdateLabel2);
    }

    public void UpdateLabel2(string x, string y, string speed, string mvm) //
    {
        label2.Text = "x: " + x + "y: " + y + "speed: " + speed + "mvm: " + mvm;
    }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var up = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.W);
        var down = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.S);
        var left = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.A);
        var right = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.D);

        if (left.IsPressed)
        {
            if (up.IsPressed == true) // if W and A keys are pressed, ->
            {
                fstr.mvmMethod("7"); // this method is triggered
                return;
            }
            if (down.IsPressed)
            {
                fstr.mvmMethod("9");
                return;
            }
            if (right.IsPressed)
            {

                fstr.mvmMethod("1");
                return;
            }

            fstr.mvmMethod("4"); //if W key is pressed, then this method is triggered
        }
        //... (other if condition statements)

        label2.Text = fstr.FinalStringBuilder();
        port.Write(fstr.FinalStringBuilder());
    }
```

**External Class:**

```
class FinalStringClass
{
    private Action<string, string, string, string> updateLabel2;
    Action<String> _x, _y, _speed, _mvm;
    string xF, yF, speedF, mvmF;

    public FinalStringClass(Action<string, string, string, string> updateLabel2)
    {
        this.updateLabel2 = updateLabel2;
    }

    public FinalStringClass(Action<String> x, Action<String> y, Action<String> speed, Action<String> mvm)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _speed = speed;
        _mvm = mvm;
    }

    public void xMethod(string x)
    {
        _x(x);
        xF = x;
    }
    public void yMethod(string y)
    {
        _y(y);
        yF = y;
    }
    public void speedMethod(string speed)
    {
        _speed(speed);
        speedF = speed;
    }
    public void mvmMethod(string mvm)
    {
        _mvm(mvm);
        mvmF = mvm;
    }
    public string FinalStringBuilder()
    {
        return xF + yF + speedF + mvmF;
    }
}
```

When working with a single parameter, everything works fine. But dealing with multiple parameters causes a problem :(

**Example of working with a single parameter (full working code):**

*Main Form*

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FFApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;
        MyClass outside;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Start();
            outside = new MyClass(UpdateLabel);
        }
        public void UpdateLabel(string str)
        {
            label1.Text = str;
        }
        private void init()
        {
            port = new SerialPort();
            port.PortName = "COM1";
            port.BaudRate = 115200;

            try
            {
                port.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
            }
        }

        public struct KeyStateInfo
        {
            private Keys key;
            private bool isPressed;
            private bool isToggled;

            public KeyStateInfo(Keys key, bool ispressed, bool istoggled)
            {
                this.key = key;
                isPressed = ispressed;
                isToggled = istoggled;
            }

            public static KeyStateInfo Default
            {
                get
                {
                    return new KeyStateInfo(Keys.None, false, false);
                }
            }

            public Keys Key
            {
                get { return key; }
            }

            public bool IsPressed
            {
                get { return isPressed; }
            }

            public bool IsToggled
            {
                get { return isToggled; }
            }
        }
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var up = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.W);
            var down = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.S);
            var left = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.A);
            var right = KeyboardInfo.GetKeyState(Keys.D);
            Keyboard kb = new Keyboard();

            if (left.IsPressed)
            {
                if (up.IsPressed == true)
                {                    
                    outside.MyMethod("7");
                    return;
                }
                if (down.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("9");
                    return;
                }
                if (right.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("1");
                    return;
                }
                outside.MyMethod("4");
            }

            if (right.IsPressed)
            {
                if (up.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("6");
                    return;
                }
                if (down.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("8");
                    return;
                }
                if (left.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("1");
                    return;
                }
                outside.MyMethod("5");
            }

            if (up.IsPressed)
            {
                if (left.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("7");
                    return;
                }
                if (right.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("6");
                    return;
                }
                if (down.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("1");
                    return;
                }
                outside.MyMethod("2");
            }

            if (down.IsPressed)
            {
                if (left.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("9");
                    return;
                }
                if (right.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("8");
                    return;
                }
                if (up.IsPressed)
                {
                    outside.MyMethod("9");
                    return;
                }
                outside.MyMethod("3");

            }

            if (!right.IsPressed && !left.IsPressed && !up.IsPressed && !down.IsPressed)
            {
                outside.MyMethod("1");
            }
       } 
        public class KeyboardInfo
        {
            [DllImport("user32")]
            private static extern short GetKeyState(int vKey);

            private KeyboardInfo()
            {

            }

            public static KeyStateInfo GetKeyState(Keys key)
            {
                short keyState = GetKeyState((int)key);
                int low = Low(keyState), high = High(keyState);
                bool toggled = low == 1;
                bool pressed = high == 1;
                return new KeyStateInfo(key, pressed, toggled);
            }

            private static int High(int keyState)
            {
                return keyState > 0 ? keyState >> 0x10
                        : (keyState >> 0x10) & 0x1;
            }

            private static int Low(int keyState)
            {
                return keyState & 0xffff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Class*

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FFApp
{
    class MyClass
    {
        Action<String> labelSetter;

        public MyClass(Action<String> labelSetter)
        {
            this.labelSetter = labelSetter;
        }
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }

        public void MyMethod(string text)
        {
            labelSetter(text);
            MyProperty = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Or is it possible within this code, to get changing values (store in a variable), when pressed W/A/D/S/W+A/W+D etc keys in order to allow building final string? ex: `string finalstring = x + y + speed + pressed_key;`

Comment: Could you please add more information about the problem you're seeing?  At first glance, your timer is going to be on a different thread, so updating your GUI from that thread will cause problems.  You should invoke the update to run on the GUI thread instead.  More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JohnCornell I added more information about the problem please help me!:)

Comment: There are multiple problems here.  To start, you should set your local variables before calling the action in FinalStringClass to avoid a race condition - if the first action probably doesn't complete before your second action is called which is probably what you're seeing.  Second, for the form, make sure that you place InvokeRequired code as mentioned above  around any edits to the form controls.  Lastly, any variables that may be accessed by different threads will need a lock around them.